# pom.xml include scalatest intellij not compiling

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I've started a relatively new project, and am trying to follow these instructions (maven) to include scalatest in my intellij project: https://www.scalatest.org/install.

I've successfully done these steps to include maven as part of my project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html#add_maven_support

now I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>independentstudy.project</groupId>
<artifactId>Connect4</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalactic_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>artima</id>
        <name>Artima Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.artima.com/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <compilerPlugin>
                <groupId>com.artima.supersafe</groupId>
                <artifactId>supersafe_2.13.5</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.12</version>
            </compilerPlugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        ...
    </executions>
</plugin>s
</project>
```

which is angry about the first set of `<dependancy>`

What am I missing?

Comment: Please explain wha tyou mean exactly with "which is angry about the first set of <dependency>"

Answer (score 0):

`<dependency>` tag must be enclosed into `<dependencies>` tag:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalactic_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Refer to Maven documentation for the pom.xml syntax reference: [Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-management).